# Site for asking questions related to mobile?

Tags: support

I'm looking for a site where I can discuss things related to mobile, but I couldn't find any relevant site in Stack Exchange (Did I overlook something?).
Please suggest if any relevant site is here in Stack Exchange.

My immediate Q was: I want to know which mobile is available in market where I can work on Linux so that I get the feeling on working in computer (good facilitated mobile). Also I will use it for other purposes like Internet etc.

Comment: I don't think a general one exists. I only know of those for the major players: [android.se] and [apple.se].

Comment: You can ask some questions about [Ubuntu Touch](http://www.ubuntu.com/phone/features) on [AskUbuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions) - but some questions generally get pelted to death with 'duplicate's..